# How to get link to readthedocs documentation to show up on github repo?

Tags: github, read-the-docs

I have a github repo with documentation served on readthedocs (say, at `https://myreponame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/`). Webhooks are set up at github so with PRs or pushes, the hook is triggered. This updates the content at the docs.

My understanding from digging around online was that once this was all set up, a link to my docs would appear on the right-hand side of my github repo main page (in the **About** section). But there is no link there. Is there some additional step I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have permission to edit the About area for the repository, click the gear icon just to its right. A modal dialog appears where you can enter a website URL and other repository metadata.